# Facebook Android SDK 4.0: newGraphPathRequest returns "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've upgraded to Facebook Android SDK 4.0. I'm trying to request a graph path:

```
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
GraphRequest req = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(token, 
    "me?fields=name,picture.width(400).height(400)",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() { ... });
```

I've stepped over the code and I verify that `token` is a perfectly valid access token, I've copied and debugged it in Graph API Explorer and it's valid. I also tried to request the exact same path by copy pasting `me?fields=name,picture.width(400).height(400)` into Graph API Explorer, using the same token, and it works.

However, when I execute the request:

```
req.executeAsync();
```

I'm getting this error in the completion handler:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be 
used to query information about the current user.","code":2500}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out the problem. I've changed the query string parameters to bundle parameters and removed them from the URL. It worked. In iOS SDK which I'm really used to, there is no such problem. Anyway. Here is the solution:

- Remove the parameters from the URL: `GraphRequest req = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(token, "me" ...);`
- Add them as a bundle.

Example:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "name,picture.width(400).height(400)");
req.setParameters(parameters);
```

It worked.

Comment: Please remember that the GraphRequest class will add parameters to the actual request URL (like the access token, among other things), so do not embed request parameters in the "path" parameter.

Comment: As you found the solution please accept it, as its listed in unanswered list.

Comment: @AnkitBansal I can now, I couldn't accept because of the 2-day rule.